# Why PIL can not read from its own generated bytes array?

Tags: python, image, stream, python-imaging-library

Consider this code

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("iamge.jpg") # Read image
image_bytes = image.tobytes() # Covert to bytes

new_image = Image.open(BytesIO(image_bytes)) # Read from BytesIO (Exception!!!)
new_image.show()
```

After execution i get this error:

> OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fa885caf258>

But when i get plain bytes from *open* function like this:

```
with open("iamge.jpg", "rb") as file_stream:
    image_bytes = file_stream.read()
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(image_bytes))
    image.show()
```

I get no error!

***How can I write a code that can deal with both types of byte arrays (with one that was generated by PIL, and another that was generated by 'open')?***

Answer (score 0):

It appears that if you want to read back from a PIL generated byte array, you need to use *frombytes* function:

```
image2 = Image.open("iamge.jpg")
image_bytes2 = image2.tobytes()

new_image = Image.frombytes("RGB", (image2.width, image2.height), image_bytes2)
new_image.show()
```

The down side of this is that you must know the *mode* (RGB e.g.) and the image size. This still feels like an unresolved problem.

---

Also, it appears, that you should not use PIL's tobytes method. Instead, if you want bytes array you should do the following:

```
with BytesIO() as output:
    with Image.open("iamge.jpg") as img:
        img.save(output, "jpeg")
    b1 = output.getvalue()
```

Even though the byte array is still not exactly the same as you would get from *open* function.